# Extract list in api.ai from user input

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es

I have a query of the following nature in API.ai
"btc, ltc, xrp to usd, inr" How can I extract the query as 
source = [btc, ltc, xrp]
destination = [usd, inr]

The number of elements in the source can be variable and the number of elements in the destination can also be variable. I am aware of the list entity and I tried it with the query. It picks up only btc in one list and puts the rest in another rest. Any suggestions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can create 2 intents ,**

1. **SingleInput**:
          a. Create a "btc, ltc, xrp" as utterance
          b. Add a Parameter $First as "SingleArray" with @sys.any
2. **MultipeInput**:
          a. Create a "btc, ltc, xrp" to "usr ind" as utterance
          b. Add a Parameter $First as "SingleArray" with @sys.any 
          b. Add a Parameter $Second as "MultipleArray" with @sys.any

Now when you issue the utterance with btn,ltc, you will get an output.

**Your Single Input:**
"btc, ltc, xrp" output has parameter $First = [btc ltc xrp]

**Your Multiple Input**
"btc, ltc, xrp to usr ind" output has parameter $First = [btc ltc xrp] and $Second = [usr ind]